# Cashing a U.S. government check as a foreigner

Tags: united-states, check

I worked in the US for 4 month as an exchange student in 2017 and just received my State Tax Return as a check. Since I live in Romania, cashing a US check is complicated, taking up to 45 days because the bank has to send the check back to the US to verify it.

Is there another method to cash a US check as a foreigner?

My roommate still has his Wells Fargo account active, even though he doesn't live in the US anymore. I thought about cashing the check in his account, as a third party one. But, after further research, I found that Wells Fargo has pretty strict rules regarding third party checks, even more strict when it comes to my only available deposit option, **the mobile one.**

I tried using PayPal, but I cannot see the **Cash a Check** option in the app, probably because of the region I'm accessing it. The same for Ingo Money - the app is not availble in my region. I tried side-loading it, but it won't connect to the network for the same reason - the region.

Comment: Unless your bank is particularly good, you're also likely to get hit with various fees and a pretty bad exchange rate... I'm not aware of a good solution if you don't have a US account and are not planning on visiting the US any time soon. :-/

Comment: A US Treasury check (Federal income tax refund) cannot be cashed; it must be deposited into a US bank account in the name of the payee(s) and not to a third party. A _State_ income tax refund check might not have the same restrictions but is likely to have _some_ restrictions.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: can you give support for that? Most Federal refunds (last I looked about 90%) are paid by electronic transfer (ACH) and those _are_ supposed to be to an account in taxpayer name [though apparently they aren't fully successful in enforcing that](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/irs-procedures/refund-inquiries/refund-inquiries-18). However the last time I got a paper check, admittedly 7 years ago, it said 'Pay to the order of [my name]' just like other checks, which should allow me to endorse it over if I wanted to (which I didn't).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 _You_ can endorse a paper US Treasury check to whomsoever you want but the recipient's bank will refuse to accept the check for deposit. "But, what if the person uses mobile deposit?" you say.  well, just let the person try; it is likely to be bounced back when someone looks at the transaction, or the Treasury refuses to pay it.

Comment: Ditto @dave_thompson_085 (a) You're mixing "cash" with "endorse to another person". Not at all the same. When I got paper checks, they looked like any other check. If I took it to the bank and instead of saying "Please deposit this to my account" I had said "I'd like to cash this", would they have said no? And if they did, what would stop me from depositing the check, and then immediately withdrawing the money in cash? The only difference I see between the two scenarios is that the second scenario requires me to have an account with the bank while the first doesn't.

Comment: (b) In any case, do you have anything to support the statement that you can't endorse a US Treasury check to another person? I've never tried to do this, but no offense intended, simply repeating the assertion that you can't is not evidence.

Comment: @Jay OK, see _[this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/48449/5760)_ by Ben Miller which contains a link to the specific regulations regarding US Treasury checks and more on this matter.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Well, I don't care enough about this question to prolong the discussion. But I read the regulations cited, 31 CFR 240, and I don't see anything in there that says you can't cash a government check or endorse it to a third party. 240.2(r) lists "unauthorized endorsements", and there's nothing in that list about endorsements by a third party, it's basically just that you can't forge someone else's signature or claim to be their legal representative. I'm not saying that you're wrong. I don't know. I'm just saying that I haven't seen any evidence that you're right.

Comment: In the interests of beating this subject to death: According to this page, http://help.walmart.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/89/~/in-store-check-cashing, Walmart will cash checks for a fee of $4 to $8. They specifically list among the types of checks that they will cash, "government checks" and "tax checks". I can't imagine that a big company like WalMart would advertise such a service if it wasn't legal.

Comment: @Jay+ I read it the same. And in addition to Walmart, https://pocketsense.com/cash-tax-refund-bank-account-6483854.html suggests Kroger and check cashing stores. 'Kroger' seems to actually be a subsidiary https://www.moneyservices.com/about-money-services/ and the check-cashing page lists Types of Checks We Can Cash which includes Income Tax Refund checks. The check-cashing stores are bottom-feeders and I won't go through their websites, but I'm quite sure if they were getting stiffed by Treasury they would stop fast.

Answer (score 5):

I tried using the advice provided in the comments, but ended up cashing it through someone's Bank of America account. Curiously, it didn't need an extra endorsement except my signature.

Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Let the check account owner go for check endorsement by endorsing at the back side of the check. Endorsed checks can be cashed easily at the bank. You have to carry a photoo id proof for cashing your check.