# U. S. Treasury Check signed "pay to the order of"

Tags: united-states, check

My son received several checks from the VA, he signed them pay to the order of me, his mother, where can I cash them? My Credit Union won't accept them.

Comment: What did they say was the reason they wouldn't accept them?  (I'm betting fraud protection.)

Comment: They didn't give me a reason. Just said they couldn't do it.

Comment: US Treasury checks are subject to special rules (cf. [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/48449/5760) for some information) and the reason that your credit union won't accept those checks is that _they_ have to certify that the original payee (your son) is known to them as their customer. Just you taking the checks to the credit union or a bank won't work; taking your son along when you make the deposit _might_ work especially if he also has an account there (he may need to endorse the checks again in front of an officer instead of just the teller) but all these might fail too.

Comment: Ask the credit union if there is any way around it. For example, my credit union initially wouldn't let me deposit a treasury check made out to both me and my wife in an account only in my name. But, if I brought her driver's license with me, they would.